# QGIS - Adding data from a raster into existing different sized polygons

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, merge

I have a raster layer with 100x100 pixel size that contains expected soil subsidence (calculated) and a polygon layer with smaller polygons that contains the measured data. I want to add the calculated data from my raster to each of the road segment polygons. As you can see in the image the polygons don't neatly fall into the raster pixels.

Ideally i would like the raster value that gets added to each polygon to be an average calculated over how much of the polygon area falls into each raster pixel.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Thank you for taking the Tour. As currently structured, your Question is asking two questions, without showing any effort to solve either. Please [Edit] the Question to focus on one approach.

Comment: With `grid` you in fact mean raster, right?

Comment: I indeed meant raster, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this using the `Raster Statistics for Polygons` Tool. Found under `SAGA` > `Features - Features-Raster Tools`.

Your calculated grid layer will be selected under `Grids` and your measured polygon layer will be selected for `Polygons`. For `Method` I think you will want to select `[3] polygon wise (cell area weighted)`.

This tool will generate a new polygon file which contains your selected statistics. Make sure you tick `Mean`, along with any other statistics you may be interested in.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion, unfortunately i get an error saying: "No spatial intersection between grid(s) and polygon layer". This is true for some of the polygons since i have 'no data' pixels in my raster. Filling those with dummy values does not seem to fix it however.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the regular "Zonal Statistics" algorithm. Turns out i made a mistake in the coordinate reference system which is why it didn't work at first.